# Use IBApi to send order with amount (USD) instead of quantity

Tags: python, api, stock, interactive-brokers

I'm currently using IBApi to send different orders to the TWS platform.
I'm using python as my main code language.

When I'm sending an order I write, for example:

```
    parent = Order()
    parent.totalQuantity = 1
```

I want to change the quantity from the number of stocks to the amount of USD I would like to buy/sell (there is an option in the TWS platform).

How can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not also advanced in TWS but I suppose there is no that kind of function. But you can create your own function that calculates number of shares for the amount of dollar.

```
# Requesting RTVolume (Time & Sales) and shortable generic ticks
self.reqMktData(1004, ContractSamples.USStockAtSmart(), "233,236", False, False, [])
```

You have to first subscribed for market data. Then you can ask for last market price of the specific stock. At that point you can store the last price of stock to specific variable let it be **price**.

```
def quantity_calc(dollar_amount, price):
  return int(dollar_amount / price)
```

I hope it will be helpful. Thnx.